# .xlsx downloading issue

Tags: iis-6, download

I have generated .xlsx reports on server, and page with direct links to these reports.
When user clicks a link, report file is downloaded, but file extension is changed to .xls.
Therefore, I can't open file correctly, only after changing of extension.
Problem occurs in IE, Firefox correctly downloads file, and Chrome saves file with name "File.xlsx.xls"

What can cause such behaviour? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed with setting of mime-type "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" for .xlsx files