# How to download file as .xlsx in Laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, browser, header

I have file saved in resource with .xlsx extension but while downloading from browser it appears as .xls

```
$path = $processor->process($result->toArray(), 'test.xlsx');
$headers = [
                'Content-Type'              => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                'Content-Length'            => filesize($path),
                'Cache-Control'             => 'must-revalidate',
                'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
                'Content-Disposition'       => 'attachment; filename="test.xlsx"'
            ];

return response()->download($path, 'test.xlsx', $headers);
```

Comment: All web browsers or this some Edge issue?

Comment: I was using chrome

Comment: FWIW: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602233/xlsx-downloading-issue Seeing a lot of results in Google. Definitely seems to happen a lot... Windows trying to protect you.

Comment: Solution provided in this thread doesn't resolve my problem because I already have this meme-type in code

Comment: For some reason thought they were different. Is the downloaded file corrupt? If you save and change extension does it open?

Comment: Was reading this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/xlsm-files-get-converted-to-xlsx-or-xls-files-when/36e9dc92-4791-49eb-8751-b2a8b1435c6e

Comment: The problem was with front code. Anyway thank you for help! :)